# Uvicorn + Django + NGinx - Error 404 while handling websockets

Tags: django, nginx, websocket, gunicorn, uvicorn

I am setting up a server with Nginx and Uvicorn to run a Django app with websockets.

Everything goes well with normal http request and I can get my webpage but my websockets handshakes always end up with a 404 error.

Everything goes well running with runserver.

here is my asgi.py file

```
import os
import django
django.setup()

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
import MYAPP.routing
import Stressing.routing

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'MYAPP.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack( URLRouter( Stressing.routing.websocket_urlpatterns ) ),
    # Just HTTP for now. (We can add other protocols later.)
})
```

my settings.py

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'MYAPP.asgi.application'

redis_host = os.environ.get('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1')

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'CONFIG': {
            'hosts': [(redis_host, 6379)],
        },
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
    },
}
```

my nginx config file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name MYAPP.box 10.42.0.1;
    
    
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location ~ ^/static {
        autoindex on;
        root /home/MYAPP;
    }

    location ~ ^/ {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/MYAPP/MYAPP.sock;
    }
    location @proxy_to_app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/MYAPP/MYAPP.sock;
    }
    location ~ ^/ws/ {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/MYAPP/MYAPP.sock;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }
}
```

The request seems to reach to socket as I can see in the gunicorn log

```
not found /ws/0
```

Does anyone has an idea of the origin of the problem?

Comment: It turned out that I was using uvicorn instead of uvicorn[standard] to be able to use the websockets.

after installing it (quite complicated as the compilation of uvloop is greedy in memory and I needed to create a swap file), I actually still have the same problem.

"Not Found: /ws/0/"

I also have the info "ASGI 'lifespan' protocol appears unsupported". I am not sure if this is impacting or not

Comment: Do you have the full config files? Gunicorn and nginx, Im trying to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed the regex expression from my Nginx file and it is working now

```
location ~ ^/ {
...
location ~ ^/ws/
```

became

```
location / {
...
location /ws/
```

so it is solved. But if someone can explain me the background of it?
I thought that Nginx always prioritizes the most specific path. Is it only working without regex? (I guess there is no ways to determine which regex is more specific?!)